# callback explanation in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, higher-order-functions

In The following  code i am using setTimeout to call the foo

```
function foo() {
  console.log('2000 milliseconds have passed since this demo started');
  }
  setTimeout(foo, 2000);
```

According to my knowledge if we won't use the parenthesis the code will just refer to the function as a pointer how the function is being an executed  called here without parenthesis

Comment: Correct. Is this only a yes and no answer?

Comment: if you add parentheses `setTimeout(foo(), 2000);` the function is executed right away, setTimeout will try to execute whatever foo returned (undefined here since you return nothing).  If foo returned a function then that function would be run after the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this example for comparison:

```js
function myFunction(callback) {
    callback();
}

function foo() {
  console.log('The foo function has been called');
}

myFunction(foo);
```

The function you pass as an argument is called by code inside `myFunction`.

`setTimeout` works in a similar way: You just aren't looking at its source code because it isn't code you wrote yourself. It comes with the browser.

Comment: Thanks 

It means we are  calling the function internally with some source code Then how  does the arrow function  with anonymous functions   gets excuted

Comment: plese look at my comment @Quentin

Comment: @VenkateshMuthyla — The same way. A function is a function. It doesn't matter if you create it with an arrow, an expression or a declaration. It doesn't matter how many variables you assign it to along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Take an example

```
function f() {
    return 10;
}

var a = f();
var b = f;
```

Here a contains 10 while b will contain a reference to function f. You can call the function on b using

```
var c = b(); // c contains 10
```

In a similar way settimeout works. If you call the function with parentheses it will get called immediately. While we dont use parentheses so the settimeout function will have a reference and call it after the specified time.